# How to i18N localize the header of a tab in GWT TabLayoutPanel

Tags: gwt, internationalization

I am unable to use the usual i18N localization of GWT to localize a tabs name ('header') in a TabLayoutPanel.

This works:

```
<g:TabLayoutPanel addStyleNames='LocationsModule' barUnit="PX" barHeight="30" >
        <g:tab>
    <g:header>Locations</g:header>
```

But I can't get any other version to work:

```
    <g:header text='{messages.layersTabTitle}' />
```

or

```
    <g:customHeader>
    <g:Label text='{messages.locationsTabTitle}' />
    <g:Label>'{messages.locationsTabTitle}'</g:Label>
    </g:customHeader>
```

anyone been able to do this, without resorting to code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to use a slightly different syntax here:

check this example: 
http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/test/com/google/gwt/uibinder/test/client/I18nMessageTest.ui.xml?r=7940

so it should be something like:

```
<g:customHeader>
    <g:Label><ui:text from="{messages.locationsTabTitle}" /></g:Label>
    </g:customHeader>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the ui:text element directly within the g:header element, avoiding the need for g:customHeader or g:Label, e.g:

```
<g:header><ui:text from="{messages.locationsTabTitle}" /></g:header>
```

(This is similar - although not quite the same - to how the file linked to by Arne uses ui:text within an h2 element: http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/test/com/google/gwt/uibinder/test/client/I18nMessageTest.ui.xml?r=7940)

Tested in GWT 2.4.0.